# What is the average time for an alpha/beta feature to be promoted to stable

Tags: xamarin

1) I am wondering how long , on average, it takes for features in alpha/beta channels to become stable and move to the stable channel?

2) is it safe to switch channels back and forth? I noticed that every time I switched channels, the components are reinstalled. What happens to the old components? are they getting removed?

3) Would it be wise to start a project in alpha/beta channel? just wanted people's opinion.

Comment: "I just wanted people's opinion" is a sign that your question is off-topic.  This would be better suited for Xamarin's forums, not SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Each release cycle is different and is subject to change. I would recommend reviewing the content @ https://releases.xamarin.com

Example: APRIL 27, 2016 / https://releases.xamarin.com/evolve-keynote-releases/

- ALPHA RELEASE – CYCLE 8  FIRST PREVIEW / Upcoming Release Dates

  - Cycle 8 Alpha – This Release!
  - Cycle 8 Beta – Fall 2016
  - Cycle 8 Stable – Fall 2016
- BETA RELEASE – CYCLE 7 RELEASE CANDIDATE / Upcoming Release Dates

  - Cycle 7 Alpha – March 10th, 2016
  - Cycle 7 Alpha 2 – March 15th, 2016
  - Cycle 7 Beta – April 11th, 2106
  - Cycle 7 Release Candidate – This Release!
  - Cycle 7 – May 2016

2) What happens to the old components? are they getting removed?

- Yes, they are being removed and the ones on the channel that you choose are being installed.

3) Would it be wise to start a project in alpha/beta channel? just wanted people's opinion.

- That is highly subjective to what your requirements are for using an alpha/beta release.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer. Somehow I missed that information when I reviewed the release website.